Find $z$ with $f^4(z) + f^3(z)g(z) + f^2(z)g^2(z) + f(z)g^3(z) + g^4(z) = 0$
This is from the latest Texas qualifier on complex analysis.

For any two non-constant, non-proportional entire functions $f, g$, show that there exists a
point $z \in \mathbb{C} $ such that $h(z)=0$ where:
$$f^4(z) + f^3(z)g(z) + f^2(z)g^2(z) + f(z)g^3(z) + g^4(z) = h(z)$$

I wanted to argue roughly like this: if $h(z)$ is never zero, then we may consider $1/h(z)$ to be entire. If it were bounded, $h(z)$ would be constant which is very unlikely, given the fact $f$ and $g$ are completely different entire functions. Thus, assuming $1/h(z)$ is unbounded means there is a sequence of points $z_n$ with $1/|h(z_n)|\rightarrow \infty$ which in turn implies that $|h(z_n)|\rightarrow 0$. I would now like to extract a subsequence which converges to a certain $x$ and by continuity $h(x)=0$ in contradiction to the fact $h$ is never zero.
The part where $h(z)$ is not constant is not completely clear. If it were constant, then say it is $c$. It is well known that monic polynomials with continuous varying coefficients have continuous varying roots that is, $V(p_z(z))=\{r_1(z),...,r_n(z)\}$ . Hence $f^4(z) -c+f^3(z) x+f^2(z) x^2+f(z)x^3+x^4=0$ has continuous varying roots and we may assume that $g(z)=r_j(z)$. Unfortunately, I do not know how to draw a contradiction out of this.
The final passage is even more obscure and I believe it is impossible to fix, as it is not clear $z_n$ would have a convergent subsequence.

If $h$ has no zeros, then $g^4(a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)$ has no zeros, where $a=f/g$. Let $w$ be a non-real fifth root of unity. Assume that $a-w$ has a zero. Then $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1$ has a zero (same order). Then $g^4$ must have a pole at that point. Contradiction. So $a$ skips all $4$ values of $w$. Therefore, $f/g$ is constant and that contradicts $f$ and $g$ note being proportional.

We have
$$
 (f(z) - g(z)) h(z) = f(z)^5 - g(z)^5
$$
or
$$
 \left( \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} - 1\right) h(z) =g(z)^4 \left( \frac{f(z)^5}{g(z)^5} - 1\right) \, .
$$
If $h$ has no zeros then the meromorphic function $f/g$ cannot take any of the four values $c_k = \exp(2\pi i k/5)$, $c=1, 2, 3, 4$ (the fifth roots of unity except $1$).
Now apply Picard's theorem and conclude that $f/g$ is constant, contrary to the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are non-proportional.

Thank you so much. I am always amazed by how quick you are. Just a question, why is it we may apply Piccard to $f/g$ if it is not entire? We want the image to be all of $\mathbb{C}$ except for a point right?

@Kadmos: $H = f/g$ is meromorphic in $\Bbb C$ and omits four values $c_k$. Then $1/(H-c_1)$ is entire and omits three values.

@Kadmos: The Great Picard theorem can be stated for entire functions or for meromorphic functions in $\Bbb C$, and both versions are equivalent. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4301084/42969.

Sorry. I thought it would follow from $f\not= c_1g$ which we have as a hypothesis, but there could be a point where $f(z_o)=c_1g(z_o)$, no? Is $1/(H-c_1)$ really entire?

@Kadmos: If $f(z_0)/g(z_0) = c_1$ then the right-hand side of the second equation  is zero, but the left-hand side is nonzero. So that is not possible.

And of course $f(z_o)=0=g(z_o)$ is also impossible as it would imply $h(z_o)=0$. So $1/(H(z)-c_1)$ is really entire. Beautiful.
